# javascript : check if JSON object exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Thought it would be simple, but it isn't... I'm trying to check if, for example, this json object :

```
var strs = {
    strprop: "VALUE_A",
    strsub: "VALUE_B",
    subsub: "VALUE_C"
}
```

exists in an Array called `regroup`. This test doesn't work :

> ```
> if(strs in regroup) {  //do stuff  }
> ```

Thanks

**EDIT**

`regroup` has this data:

```
[
    {
        "strprop": "répond ",
        "strsub": "au besoin suivant :",
        "subsub": "Economiser son carburant."
    },
    {
        "keyword": "coûte cher"
    },
    {
        "strprop": "répond ",
        "strsub": "au besoin suivant :",
        "subsub": "Economiser son carburant."
    },
    {
        "keyword": "carburant pollue"
    }
]
```

Comment: it wouldn`t work. In regroup another objects? In javascript new Object != new Object

Comment: What is the content of regroup? When should the condition evaluate to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic methods available for comparing *object with another object in JS.*  Instead there is a way suggested in this @crazyx 's [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/1671639)

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

In your case,

```
for (var i=0; i<regroup.length; i++) { //iterate through each object in an array
     if (JSON.stringify(regroup[i]) === JSON.stringify(strs) ) {
             alert("EQUALS");
      }
}
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/sxfHA/)

> **FYI:** *order of the key/value pair should be **same*** else the above method will fail, [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/sxfHA/1/).

Comment: @Spadon_: This isn't what you should do. It's unnecessarily  expensive, and it could fail without warning. JSON serialization does not guarantee the order in which the object properties will be serialized. It's a bad idea to use constructs that make no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strs={strprop: "VAL_A", strsub: "VAL_B", subsub: "VAL_C"}; var reg=[strs, 1, "2345"]; for(elmnt in reg){ if(reg[elmnt]==strs)
```